# Given a Ruby DateTime how can I determine if it represents a day in the current work week?

Tags: ruby, date

I have a Ruby [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) instance and I would like to know it is within the current week (Monday-Sunday). I'm not using Rails.

My guess is that I'd need to get the dates of Monday and Sunday for the current week and test whether my date lies between them.

Comment: datetime.strptime - use that to get week-of-year and day-of-week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date.parse("Monday") # get the Monday date of current week
=> #<Date: 2015-10-26 ((2457322j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Date.today.between?(Date.parse("Monday"), Date.parse("Monday") + 7)
=> true

DateTime.now.between?(Date.parse("Monday"),Date.parse("Monday") + 7)
=> true
```